# Differing DTOs for request/response

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs, openapi, dto

I am working with MongoDB and subdocuments. MongoDB generates additional fields that can't be set in a POST, only able to GET them.
In other words: different `dto`s.

I am using Swagger and OpenAPI to autogenerate the API documentation and would like to not repeat myself (dry) by using the same definitions multiple times.

My first idea was to `extend`:

```
export class CreateSingleAttributeRequestDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    example: 10,
    description: 'Attribute Value',
    format: 'integer',
  })
  @IsInt()
  readonly value: number = SINGLE_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_DEFAULT;
}

export class FetchSingleAttributeResponseDto extends CreateSingleAttributeRequestDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    example: 30,
    description: 'GENERATED. Cost of the attribute.',
    format: 'integer',
  })
  @IsInt()
  readonly ap?: number;
}

export class CreateAttributeRequestDto {
  readonly attributes?: {
    readonly cou?: CreateSingleAttributeRequestDto;
    readonly sgc?: CreateSingleAttributeRequestDto;
  }
}

export class FetchAttributeResponseDto extends CreateAttributeRequestDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    example: 98,
    description: 'GENERATED. Sum of all values of the 8 attributes',
    format: 'integer',
  })
  @IsInt()
  readonly total?: number;
}
```

(If you are having problems understanding the semantics: This is code for an RPG character creator. You pay with points for your attributes and for compatibility with other features, thr cost are autogenerated on creation on the document.)

Problem with that is: `FetchAttributeResponseDto extends CreateAttributeRequestDto` - which does not have the additional fields set in `FetchSingleAttributeResponseDto`

My idea would be to - instead of extending `CreateAttributeRequestDto` - "copy" it - and instead use  `readonly cou?: FetchSingleAttributeResponseDto`

This would violate the dry principle tho - and it doesnt feel right. Is there a better solution?

Also: the create MongoDB Document has additional fields like `_id, __v, createdAt, updatedAt` - because I dont want to write all these 4 keys every time, I was thinking about creating an additional class for those that I extend - unfortunately, TS does not support multiinheritance afaik. How would you implement that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@nestjs/mapped-type`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/mapped-types) for this. And use either `OmitType`, `PickType` or `PartialType` while extending like:

```
export class UpdateUserInput extends PartialType(CreateUserInput) {}
```

More info at this official [blogpost](https://trilon.io/blog/introducing-mapped-types-for-nestjs).

Comment: This is what I am doing for my `UpdateDtos` - but that is not the question. `FetchAttribute` has a field called `attribute`, but instead of `cou` and `sgc` being of type `CreateSingleAttribute`, they should be of type `FetchSingleAttribute` to contain the generated `ap` field